# Prevent row insertion if foreign_key is not null in the referenced row

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints

Simple table with primary key as the first column and foreign key referencing the same table as the second column.

```
1 | null
2 | 1
```

I want to prevent insertion of a row whose fk would reference a row whose fk is not null. E.g. insertion of the row below should be prevented:

```
3 | 2
```

How can it be achieved? I'v tried the following

```
ALTER TABLE t 
ADD CONSTRAINT t_check 
CHECK (
    fk not in (select t.pk from t1 t where t.pk = fk and t.fk is not null)
);
```

but got

```
ERROR: cannot use subquery in check constraint
```

as expected.

Comment: You can create function which returned Boolean and use this function in check clause. Inside function you can write any query and any if clauses to checking your data.

Comment: @RaminFaracov I've done it by using this approach. Thanks.